# Average of every X rows using only ONE select in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, average

I have the following table

```
product | price
------------------
 A      | 10
 B      | 20
 C      | 45
 D      | 47
 E      | 10
 F      | 60
 G      | 15
 H      | 15
 I      | 90
```

And I need to get something like (for X = 3):

```
products  |  avg
------------------
 A        |  25    -- 10+20+45
 D        |  39    -- 47+10+60
 G        |  40    -- 15+15+90
```

This has to be done using only one SELECT command!

Is it possible to do this?
DBMS: MSSQL

Comment: What happens if x = 2? Or 5? This is very strange with an oddball requirement. Is this for school?

Comment: How are you choosing "A", "D", and "G"?

Comment: @SeanLange, if x = 2 or 5, it just takes average of remaining values

Comment: @GordonLinoff, 'A', 'D' and 'G' are the first letters of each group

Answer (score 3):

If you want these in groups of 3 based on the name, you can use `row_number()` to assign a number and then aggregate:

```
select min(product), avg(price)
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by product) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by (seqnum - 1) / 3;  -- SQL Server does integer division
```

Comment: I would make it this way but there's a condition that you have to use only one SELECT without temporary tables.

Comment: Well that is actually a single query with a subquery and not temporary tables. Maybe you can ask your teacher what he want. I dont think you can make it simpler than this.

Comment: @J.Doe . . . This is one select *statement*.  I don't know what a "select command" is in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't tried anything yet, I'll give you a general strategy to get you started.

Group by row number divided by 3 (or *x*).    Order the row number by Product.